# Computing limits from the left and right and getting the same answer which isn't correct

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, physics, discontinuity, code

When I use the following code:

```
p=(-2 + E^(1 - t) + t) HeavisideTheta[1 - t] + 
      1/1000000000000000000 E^-t (1000000000000000000 + 
         E (-1000000000000000000 - 
            1000000000999999997999999999 (-1 + E^(
               1/1000000000)) E) + (-1000000000999999997999999999 E^2 + 
            E^t (-999999999000000002000000001 + 
               1000000000000000000000000000 t)) HeavisideTheta[
           2 - t] + (1000000000999999997999999999 E^(
             2000000001/1000000000) + 
            E^t (1000000000000000002000000001 - 
               1000000000000000000000000000 t)) HeavisideTheta[
           2000000001/1000000000 - t]);
Plot[p, {t, 0, 5}]
```

I see the following output:

[image]

The jump in the graph is representing a voltage peak, now I want to find the limit from the left and from the right. So I used the code: `Limit[p,t->2,Direction->1]` and `Limit[p,t->2,Direction->-1]` but it both gave me the same answer which is not possible, where is my mistake?

Comment: The left limit of $p$ at $x=2$ seems correct.

Comment: Consider `Plot[p, {t, 2 - 1*^-9, 2 + 2*^-9}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the terms

```
HeavisideTheta[2000000001/1000000000 - t]
```

and

```
HeavisideTheta[2 - t]
```

So you have multiple jumps, not right at the point 2.

Indeed, set p[t] to your function, and evaluate:

```
{p[2], p[2.00000000000001], p[2.0000000001], p[2.00001], p[2.01]} // N
{0.767456, 0.767435, 0.567456, -1.23253, -1.22028}
```

Comment: So is my function is not discontinuous? So I can't take the limits as I originally wanted?

Comment: @Michael E2 suggests a plot that makes it look continuous, as do spot evaluations like above.